# Node.js UDP subnet broadcast fails on linux

Tags: javascript, node.js, linux, udp, subnet

This is a gist of simplified Node javascript code to test.

https://gist.github.com/d3x0r/315c87e8d2d65543d8689356d80f4c76

This creates a socket for each interface address, computes the subnet broadcast address, and then sends every second, for 4 seconds, to each computed address.

This works on windows.  It never receives on linux.
If the process is on at the same time on windows and linux, then windows receives the subnet broadcasts from the linux computer, but not vice-versa.

Answer (score 0):

I did some more testing, added UDP support to a node addon that uses just standard low level sendto, bind, socket etc.  It still failed.

I found this that gave me a hint  http://developerweb.net/viewtopic.php?pid=32260#p32260

I have to use the subnet broadcast address in bind() in order to receive the subnet broadcast under linux.  It still sends from the appropriate IP address.